# Multiple WAN connections, same server, ssl certificates

Tags: ssl, iis

Web site on IIS.  We have an SSL certificate for the primary WAN connection which is working.

When we lose the primary Internet connection, users need to securely connect using the backup connection.

Is it possible to connect another certificate to the site or will one certificate handle both WAN connections?

Comment: Certificates for a website have nothing to do with connections, only with DNS names. What is your *actual* problem? Have you done any testing?

Comment: **We have an SSL certificate for the primary WAN connection which is working.** - That doesn't make sense. Can you clarify your configuration and your problem?